# Moving background with Sprite Kit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have started to work with Sprite Kit. I am working on a game that has moving background. Now I was wondering how would I make to move background faster if I touch the screen and how to move background normal when I release my finger.

I am moving my background like this now.

Code starts like this:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
     if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

     [self addBackground]


};
return self;
}

 -(void)addBackground{


SKTexture* background = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"backgroundImage"];

SKAction* moveBackground = [SKAction moveByX:-1704*2 y:0 duration:0.004 * background.size.width*2];
SKAction* putOnStart = [SKAction moveByX:1704*2 y:0 duration:0];
SKAction* moveForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[moveBackground, putOnStart]]];

 for( int i = 0; i < 2 + self.frame.size.width / ( background.size.width * 2 ); ++i )      {
    SKSpriteNode* sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:background size:CGSizeMake(1704 ,320)];
         sprite.position = CGPointMake(i * sprite.size.width, sprite.size.height / 2);
    [background runAction:moveForever];
    [self addChild:sprite];
}
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    touching = YES;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    touching = NO;
}
```

I initialize this when view appears. Now the thing is that I would like to update the duration of `SKAction moveBackround`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the previous answer. I completely misread your question and had way too much coffee :)

Take a look at this code for moving a background. As you asked, it has the capability to move at 2 speeds depending on whether a touch is registered or not.

```
#import "MyScene.h"

// this a from a project I did for an iPhone 5s
// the background image I used is 2048 wide by 640 high and is a @2x.png

 static const float CONSTANT_MOVE_POINTS_PER_SEC = 300.0;

 static inline CGPoint CGPointMultiplyScalar(const CGPoint a,
                                             const CGFloat b)
{
    return CGPointMake(a.x * b, a.y * b);
}

 static inline CGPoint CGPointAdd(const CGPoint a,
                                  const CGPoint b)
{
    return CGPointMake(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
}

@implementation MyScene {
    SKNode *_bgLayer;
    int _gameSpeedPlus;
    NSTimeInterval _dt;
    NSTimeInterval _lastUpdateTime;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        _bgLayer = [SKNode node];
        [self addChild:_bgLayer];
        _gameSpeedPlus = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            SKSpriteNode * bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background"];
            bg.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
            bg.position = CGPointMake(i * bg.size.width, 0);
            bg.name = @"bg";
            [_bgLayer addChild:bg];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)moveBg {
    CGPoint bgVelocity = CGPointMake(-(CONSTANT_MOVE_POINTS_PER_SEC + _gameSpeedPlus), 0);
    CGPoint amtToMove = CGPointMultiplyScalar(bgVelocity, _dt);
    _bgLayer.position = CGPointAdd(_bgLayer.position, amtToMove);

    [_bgLayer enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"bg"
                               usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop){
                                   SKSpriteNode * bg = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
                                   CGPoint bgScreenPos = [_bgLayer convertPoint:bg.position
                                                                     toNode:self];
                                   if (bgScreenPos.x <= -bg.size.width) {
                                       bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.position.x+bg.size.width*2,
                                                             bg.position.y);
                               }
                           }];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    _gameSpeedPlus = 200; // change value to increase or decrease speed
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    _gameSpeedPlus = 0;
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    if (_lastUpdateTime) {
        _dt = currentTime - _lastUpdateTime;
    } else {
        _dt = 0;
    }
    _lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
        [self moveBg];
    }


@end
```

Comment: Hey. But I am not calling changeBackgroundSpeed anywhere?

Comment: How should that work? The SKAction is created and than looped forever. So it would be always low speed.

Comment: @wumm - You can a SKAction to a SKSpriteNode using [self runAction:_playerAnimation withKey:@"anyName"]. Then you can remove (stop it) it at any time using [self removeActionForKey:@"animation"]. This works regardless of whether the action is looped forever or just a single run. Source (runAction:withKey:) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/runAction:withKey: